# Find the largest possible order of an element of $\frac{\Bbb{Z}_{12}\times\Bbb{Z}_3\times\Bbb{Z}_6}{\left<(8,2,4)\right>}.$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group

I find the following problem tough:

Find the largest possible order of an element of the quotient group

$$
Q = \frac{\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{6}}{\left<(8,2,4)\right>}.
$$

So far I've got that the order of $\left<(8,2,4)\right>$ is $3$, so $|Q| = 72$. But I think I am lacking the basic intuition behind quotient groups involving direct product of groups. So the question has this second, added personlly, part: what is the intuition behind these quotient groups?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might think about it as follows. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $x=(8,2,4)$. As you observed, it has order three. If $u=(\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c})$ is an arbitrary element of  $G=\Bbb{Z}_{12}\times\Bbb{Z}_3\times \Bbb{Z}_6$, then in the coset $u+H$ there is a unique element of the form $(\overline{a'},0,\overline{c'})$. All because $\gcd(2,3)=1$. In other words, by adding a suitable multiple of $x$ you can make the middle component equal to zero. And the multiple that work is unique. This leads to an IMO useful description of $Q$.

Comment: (cont'd) Basically I would use the fact that $x$ and $2x=(4,1,2)$ generate the same subgroup $H$, and that $1$ in the middle is a trigger. But, this a bit ad hoc.In a general case you need to work a bit harder. It is not always the case that we can write $G=H\oplus K$ as an internal direct sum like here.

Comment: If you know the method of Smith normal form, you could also solve it by calculating the Smith normal form of $\begin{bmatrix} 8 & 12 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 0 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q$ is the homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z_{12}\times\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_6$ under the canonical projection $p$.  Any element of the image under a homomorphism must have order dividing $12$.

The only possibility for an element of order $12$ would be the image under $p$ of an element of order $12$.  Consider $(1,0,0)$.  It maps to $\overline{(1,0,0)}$, whose order is $12$.

Comment: The result is correct, but the method is unjustified and downright weird. If, instead, we moded out the subgroup $H$ generated by $(4,0,0)$ are you really saying that becayse $(1,0,0)+H=(5,0,0)+H$, and $(5,0,0)$ has order $12$ in the original group, then we can conclude? Observe that in this case the order of $(1,0,0)+H$ would be equal to four.

Comment: The point is that $12$ is the smallest multiple of $(1,0,0)$ that is in $H$. I reduced the possibilities to divisors of $12$, then found an element of order $12$. Nothing weird or unjustified. Who said anything about $(9,2,4)$'s order in the original group? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I found it a little hard to be methodical at the end.  There are $72$ elements of order $12$ whose images to check.  But the first couple I tried "worked".  Maybe you can find a way to be more methodical.

Comment: Ok, that is exactly the point that $12$ is the smallest multiple of $(1,0,0)$ belonging to $H$. I am puzzled about the "need" to include $(9,2,4)$ into the discussioin. Why not $\overline{(1,0,0)}$ when that is what you are really looking at :-)

Comment: I almost said the same thing to you.  It could be considered a little awkward.  I'll probably change it.  Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: No problem. Sorry about misunderstanding your thinking at first.